# Angular Test a function that updates a value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I would like to test this function that only updates a Boolean variable. But when I test with toHaveBeenCalled method it passes because the function has been called. However when I read the value of the variable it never updates even though the function was successfully called.

See the code below for more details, the first portion is the main method and the second is the test.

```
// Main Code.
variableToUpdate: boolean = false;
updateVariable(){
  this.variableToUpdate = true;
}

// Passing Test
it('should call the function', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'updateVariable');
  component.updateVariable();
  expect(component.updateVariable).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

// Failing Test
it('should update the value of the variable', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'updateVariable');
  component.updateVariable();
  expect(component.variableToUpdate).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: fixture.detectChanges();
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/change-detection/

Comment: Is `ToEqual` a typo? Should be `toEqual` same with `ToHaveBeenCalled`

Comment: @robert I both have them correctly in the code. I was typing this from memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second test remove this line:

`spyOn(component, 'updateVariable');`

to look like this:

```
  it('should update the value of the variable', () => {
    component.updateVariable();
    expect(component.variableToUpdate).toEqual(true);
  });
```

`spyOn` will not call your original implementation, to achieve that you need to do this:

```
spyOn(obj, 'method').and.callThrough();
```

Whole test case with `spyOn`:

```
it('should update the value of the variable', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'updateVariable').and.callThrough();
    component.updateVariable();
    expect(component.variableToUpdate).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: is andCallThrough() a valid method? I am not able to see that in the intellisense.

Comment: @DavidSagang sorry it should be `and.callThrough();` I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Robert for your help.